# nuxt.js localhost:3000 not running

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, localhost

As I'm currently going from React to Vue.js, i failed with running my localhost on Port 3000. Getting the below error message. Looks like there is a problem with the server.

Down below a added the installation process so that it gets clearer how it's installed.
Also you can find the error message when running npm run dev.

Any suggestions what the problem could be?

Installation process

```
create-nuxt-app v5.0.0
✨  Generating Nuxt.js project in cryptocheck24.org
? Project name: cryptocheck24.org
? Programming language: JavaScript
? Package manager: Npm
? UI framework: None
? Template engine: HTML
? Nuxt.js modules: (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert se
lection)
? Linting tools: (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert sele
ction)
? Testing framework: Jest
? Rendering mode: Universal (SSR / SSG)
? Deployment target: Server (Node.js hosting)
? Development tools: (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert 
selection)
? Continuous integration: None
? Version control system: Git
```

Error message

```
> cryptocheck24.org@1.0.0 dev
> nuxt


   ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                       │
   │   Nuxt @ v2.15.8                      │
   │                                       │
   │   ▸ Environment: development          │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side          │
   │   ▸ Target:      server               │
   │                                       │
   │   Listening: http://localhost:3000/   │
   │                                       │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯

ℹ Preparing project for development                                   16:25:39
ℹ Initial build may take a while                                      16:25:39
ℹ Discovered Components: .nuxt/components/readme.md                   16:25:39
✔ Builder initialized                                                 16:25:39
✔ Nuxt files generated                                                16:25:39

● Client █████████████████████████ compiling (0%)  
 

◯ Server
  

node:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/remo/Desktop/cryptocheck24.org/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/remo/Desktop/cryptocheck24.org/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/Users/remo/Desktop/cryptocheck24.org/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /Users/remo/Desktop/cryptocheck24.org/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /Users/remo/Desktop/cryptocheck24.org/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /Users/remo/Desktop/cryptocheck24.org/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/remo/Desktop/cryptocheck24.org/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/remo/Desktop/cryptocheck24.org/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Comment: You did no other configuration beyond starting the project? Or did you do some additional things after (like installing some packages)?

Comment: nope, nothing that's why it looks strange to me. Even when trying a new installation and running npm run dev it doesn't work.

Comment: What is your Node version? 14 or below?

Comment: i got version v18.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Since the v5, a Node v14 version is required: https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/releases/tag/v5.0.0

So you can either try that. It works on my side with the latest LTS: Node v16.

---

Or fallback into using the v4 of the CLI.
That version runs perfectly for ages already

```
npx create-nuxt-app my-cool-app
```

and is well battle-tested!

PS: I've opened this issue btw: https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/1014

Comment: hmm no chance to get it running unfortunately

Comment: @RemoFurrer tried both solutions?

Comment: yes i did but still error

Comment: @RemoFurrer same for both?

Comment: it's just so strange. deleted vue cli completely and reinstalled it to the latest version but got 5 vulnerabilities. So there is something wrong with vue

Comment: @RemoFurrer this is an NPM thing tbh. Try with yarn/pnpm.

Comment: @RemoFurrer also, it's not Vue CLI here but rather the Nuxt one.